# How to get info about fb2 book in Java for Android?

Tags: java, android, fb2

Adding book from a file feature in android app is in progress.

I want to eject cover (as PNG), author's name, title and text content from **.fb2** file.

How can I do it via Java for Android?

There is a code:

```
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String text;
    private String author;
    private Image cover;

    public Book(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File bookFile = new File(path);
        if (!bookFile.isFile()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
        //what i have to do there?
    }
}
```